# payload validation is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, hapi.js, joi

Payload validation for an array called creator isn't working properly
This is the payload validation :

```
   creator: {
            _id:Joi.string().required(), 
            name: Joi.string().required()
        }
```

The creator is supposed to be mandatory field and should throw an error if not entered as an input in http body.
This is the mongoose schema :

```
   var User = {
        _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Admin'},
        name: {type: String, ref: 'Admin'}
    };
    var Note = new Schema({
    creator: User });
```

Currently if I don't pass creator in http body it still works fine without it.

Comment: why do you put a moongose scheme in a  joi validation scheme? can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have different files the second part is model and 1st part is payload validation. I got it to work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the mongoose side of it but if the question is "how to validate an array with Joi"

```
creator: Joi.array().items(Joy.object({
            _id:Joi.string().required(), 
            name: Joi.string().required()
        }))
```

Since you named it "creator" (singular) and want an array it sounds like you might want to accept either a single object or an array of objects.  You can do that with `.single()` at the end:

```
creator: Joi.array().items(Joy.object({
            _id:Joi.string().required(), 
            name: Joi.string().required()
        })).single()
```

This will accept both `creator: { _id: '' , name: ''}` and `creator: [{_id: '', name: ''}]`

Comment: Got it. Although I mentioned `.required()` instead of `.single()` but tried with `.single()` as well. thanks